# Apache httpd error "proxy: ap_get_scoreboard_lb" with ProxyPass

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, tomcat, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I set up apache to proxy for tomcat but I am getting the following error when I target the page. I sometimes get a blank page or a 503:

[Error]

```
[Mon Dec 03 04:58:16 2012] [error] proxy: ap_get_scoreboard_lb(2) failed in child 29611 for worker proxy:reverse
[Mon Dec 03 04:58:16 2012] [error] proxy: ap_get_scoreboard_lb(1) failed in child 29611 for worker https://localhost:8443/
[Mon Dec 03 04:58:16 2012] [error] proxy: ap_get_scoreboard_lb(0) failed in child 29611 for worker http://localhost:8080/
```

I have two vhosts configured on the vm as follows:

[http host]

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.mysite.net
  ServerAlias mysite.net

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ retry=0
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/ retry=0
</VirtualHost>
```

[ssl vhost]

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.mysite.net
        ServerAlias mysite.net

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
        ServerSignature On

        SSLEngine on
        SSLProxyEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / https://localhost:8443/ retry=0
        ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:8443/ retry=0

</VirtualHost>
```

My system details are: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_jk/1.2.32 mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1
mod proxy_http is also enabled.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems there's a difference between stopping and then starting apache and doing a `apachectl graceful` restarting (i.e. actually stopping and starting as opposed to **apachectl restart**) as found at [this site](http://apache-http-server.18135.n6.nabble.com/Error-proxy-ap-get-scoreboard-lb-90-failed-in-child-td4746072.html):

```
This is a bit of a guess, and probably wrong, but does stopping and 
starting the server rather than restarting (they're different, 
restarting (including gracefully) doesn't kill the master process) 
help? As I understand it, there are issues in mod_proxy regarding the 
scoreboard size when changes to the config are made between restarts.
```

Comment: FWIW, `apachectl restart` isn't enough either; I had to do an `apachectl stop; apachectl start` to prevent this error from occurring (also with Apache httpd 2.2.2).

Comment: @NicholasRiley by Yeah That's what I meant by restarting. I perhaps should have been clearer on that point.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was getting the same errors when I was changing a forward proxy configuration and then restarting using `graceful`.